# Application of Complex Numbers (Electrical Engineering)

Tags: complex-numbers

I was just wondering how complex numbers can be applied in electrical engineering and why we use complex numbers over regular, real numbers for this application (e.g what capabilities does the complex number have that real numbers do not in electrical engineering)

Thanks !

I have done some research concerning impedances and understand how they are written in complex form, however I am still confused why complex numbers are necessary in this field over regular numbers.

Comment: Try searching for _complex numbers electrical engineering_ https://www.google.com/search?q=complex+numbers+electricial+engineering&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1

Comment: And it gets even worse: electrical/electronic engineering usually has a one semester course in Complex Functions...

Comment: Current,voltage are periodic rotating vectors/phasors  and so even resistance is complex... and to study phase or relative direction complex numbers are a must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In circuits theory, complex numbers can be used to model impedences which is impossible using real numbers (at a special case where all the elements are resistors it also could be attained using real numbers) but when there are also capacitors and solenoids an analytical approach can be reached only using complex numbers because of affording both magnitude and phase.

Comment: In addition, I would say that alternating current power sources can also have a complex number representation. This allows the analyst to use precisely the same procedures for modeling passive AC circuits as are used in resistive circuits: the methods are all algebraic. Now I would hasten to point out that this complex number method assumes everything is steady state (you've reached the asymptotic behavior). If you need to analyze the transient behavior, you need to solve the DE's.